# Everytime i try to create a new project ,by default project is created with a default library Appcompat_v7

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

While creating android project i am getting below warning in console in eclipse:

By default main activity is extended by `ActionBarActivity`.How to retreive old project template.

```
[2014-05-11 22:07:59 - appcompat_v7_5] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\gippy\workspace\appcompat_v7_5\bin\jarlist.cache
```

And appcompat_v7_x folder is created along with project folder in eclipse.

Can Anyone Please help me to get the solution.

Comment: Hey friends .......I am here to find a solution to my problem..and i was expecting help from you senior guys.....not vote down......

Comment: A new appcompat library project with every new project is now the default behaviour with the latest tools, see: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67513

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have updated your editor or downloaded new adt bundle. appcompact v7 is added automatically now. As for the warining try selecting the project, click on Project>Properties > Android and choose a lower API. If an error persists, try Project >Properties > Clean.

Comment: what about the  appcompat_v7_x added every time i create a new project

Comment: It would be appreciated if you can guide me how can i set old pattern of project with only activity_main.xml rather than  activity_main.xml and fragment_main.xml